# Pheno Menon's number challenge

Tags: mathematics

Today Professor Pheno Menon challenged me with a puzzle:

"I will give you a composite number $n$. You need to give me a list of $n$ integers, all between $1$ to $n$ (those two included), so that the sum of their cubes is equal to the square of their sum. Can you always do that?

I said "That's easy! I can just give the numbers $1,2,\cdots,n$."

He replied, "Not so fast, my friend! There are some more conditions: the list must have a unique minimum and a unique maximum, and it **mustn't** be exactly the same as $1,2,\cdots ,n$ (up to permutation, of course). Now tell me, is it always possible?"

I tried for some time, but couldn't quite get to any conclusion. Maybe you can help?

<sub><sub>I'd prefer a solution with completely elementary maths, not higher than high school mathematics.</sub></sub>

Comment: What do you mean by unique minimum and unique maximum?

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil: There should be only one minimum number and only one maximum number, i.e [1,2,2,2,n] is allowed, but [1,1,2,3,n,n] is not.

Comment: "all between $1$ to $n$ (those two included)" - does that mean $1$ and $n$ MUST be included in the list (and therefore they are the unique minimum and maximum) or just that they CAN be?

Comment: @randal'thor they just can be included.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Is it always possible?

> Yes, it is always possible.

Proof:

> Suppose $n=pq$ is a non-trivial factorization of $n$, and you have two lists $a_1, a_2, ..., a_p$ and $b_1, b_2, ..., b_q$ for which the sum of cubes is equal to the square of the sum, and each has a unique maximum and a unique minimum. That is, we have $(\sum a)^2 = \sum a^3 = A$ and $(\sum b)^2 = \sum b^3 = B$.
>
>  Now let's consider the list of pairwise products $c = (a_ib_j)$ (for every i,j). Clearly, $c$ has $n$ elements. Now let's compute $(\sum c)^2$ and $\sum c^3$:
>
>  $\sum c^3 = \sum a_i^3b_j^3 = (\sum a_i^3)(\sum b_j^3) = AB$
>  $(\sum c)^2 = (\sum a_ib_j)^2 = [(\sum a_i)(\sum b_j)]^2 = (\sum a_i)^2(\sum b_j)^2 = AB$
>
>  So $c$ also satisfies the property that the sum of the cubes is the square of the sum, and given that $a$ and $b$ had unique maxima and minima, $c$ has a unique maximum and a unique minimum as well.
>
>  It remains to show that suitable lists $a$ and $b$ exist. But this is obvious, because as said in the question we can take $a = 1, 2, ..., p$ and $b = 1, 2, ..., q$, and the final list $c$ cannot be equal to $1,2,...,n$ because it has at least two equal numbers $a_1b_2 = a_2b_1 = 2$.

Comment: You also need to establish that the list you constructed isn't just 1,2,3,...,pq. (This is not terribly difficult.)